# Why is the derivative of $b$ W.R.T $x$ $0$ in this problem?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} - ax - b\right)} =0$$

And you need to find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Now what will be the derivative of $b$ W.R.T $x$.

I have seen people answering $0$. But I don't understand how is it $0$ because $b$ does depend on $x$. For example if $x$ was approaching 100, we would get a different value of $b$ now. So $b$ does depend on $x$, so why do we take the derivative of $b$ W.R.T $x$ as $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially trying to find the slant asymptote of $(x^2+1)/(x+1)$ when $x\to +\infty$. A rational function has a slant asymptote if and only if the degree of the numerator is precisely one higher than the degree of the numerator. By long-division (for instance), it's easy to see that $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = x-1 +\frac{2}{x+1}.$$Thus $a=1$ and $b=-1$. I do not know what you mean by taking the derivative of $b$ with respect to $x$: both $a$ and $b$ are determined constants. The parameter $b$ is *not* a function of $x$. The limit is zero and you don't have any equality between the rational function and the asymptote, just the limit relation (hence *asymptote*).

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} - ax - b = x \left(\frac{x+ \frac{1}{x} }{x+1}-a\right) -b$$

First, if $a \neq 1$, then the above parenthesis does not tend to $0$ and then, the wholde expression cannot tend to $0$. So necessarily, $a=1$. Secondly, $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1} - x - b = x \left(\frac{ \frac{1}{x}-1 }{x+1}\right) -b$$

which tends to $-1-b$, so for this to be equal to $0$, you must have $b=-1$.

So the values are $(a,b)=(1,-1)$, and your question on the derivatives has not a lot of sense.